# Particles not Show in UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, particles, particle-system

I want to show Particle System or Ellipsoid Particle System in my scene (2D Game). My Background is a sprite and when I show explosion from particle system it does not display.

It only comes to display when I reduce the Alpha of my Background sprite. Which makes Bg faint and that is not anyone will want.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It may have several reasons for this:

1. Your particle system may use Z-coordinate and locate behind sprite.
2. You shader particle shader have queue value less than background's shader queue